In Sharepoint lists, is it possible to create a rule for an Image column?
I have a SharePoint list that contains an Image column. In the create rule, this column isn't selectable. However, I'm wondering if there's a workaround using Power Automate to send an email to a user whenever this column is updated, except when the value is deleted.
I've previously attempted to use Power Automate for similar workflows, but I encountered the problem of lacking a previous column value for comparison; hence, the condition was never met. An additional column was suggested to store the previous value, but I'm concerned that with images, this might result in too much data.
I would appreciate any better solutions if anyone has any to offer!
